# bootstrap 4 - placing one table under another and centering

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, row, center

I want to have my tables centered horizontally and I expect them to be displayed one under another. Using some bootstrap 4 classes I've managed to have the tables displayed very unevenly or to have one missing. That is why I am looking for help, and I'm delivering the code, where the two tables exists in one row.

```
<div class="mt-3 d-flex justify-content-center">
        <div class="text-center p-2">
        <table class="table table-dark table-striped w-auto">  
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-primary">
            <th>Przystanek</th>
            <th>(A)</th>     
            <th>(A)</th>   
            <th>(A)</th>   
            <th>(A)</th>   
            </tr>
        </thead>        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Lidzbark Warmiński</th>
            <td>08:00</td>
            <td>12:00</td>
            <td>15:00</td>
            <td>19:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Kraszewo</th>
            <td>08:20</td>
            <td>12:20</td>
            <td>15:20</td>
            <td>19:20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Dobre Miasto</th>
            <td>08:30</td>
            <td>12:30</td>
            <td>15:30</td>
            <td>19:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Olsztyn PKP</th>
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td>13:00</td>
            <td>16:00</td>
            <td>20:00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>  


        <div class="text-center p-2">
        <table class="table table-dark table-striped w-auto ">  
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-primary">
            <th>Przystanek</th>
            <th>(A)</th>     
            <th>(A)</th>   
            <th>(A)</th>   
            <th>(A)</th>   
            </tr>
        </thead>        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Olsztyn PKP</th>
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td>13:00</td>
            <td>17:00</td>
            <td>21:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Dobre Miasto</th>
            <td>09:30</td>
            <td>13:30</td>
            <td>17:30</td>
            <td>21:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Kraszewo</th>
            <td>09:50</td>
            <td>13:50</td>
            <td>17:50</td>
            <td>21:50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Lidzbark Warmiński</th>
            <td>10:00</td>
            <td>14:00</td>
            <td>18:00</td>
            <td>22:00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>
        </div>  
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need set flex direction to column instead rows (that is by default), and then align items. In bootstrap it will be simply `flex-column` and `align-items-center`.

Docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/

Also this div `<div class="text-center p-2">` is not needed. Just set text-center on table.

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="mt-3 d-flex align-items-center flex-column">
    <table class="table table-dark table-striped w-auto text-center m-2">  
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-primary">
            <th>Przystanek</th>
            <th>(A)</th>     
            <th>(A)</th>   
            <th>(A)</th>   
            <th>(A)</th>   
            </tr>
        </thead>        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Lidzbark Warmiński</th>
            <td>08:00</td>
            <td>12:00</td>
            <td>15:00</td>
            <td>19:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Kraszewo</th>
            <td>08:20</td>
            <td>12:20</td>
            <td>15:20</td>
            <td>19:20</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Dobre Miasto</th>
            <td>08:30</td>
            <td>12:30</td>
            <td>15:30</td>
            <td>19:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Olsztyn PKP</th>
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td>13:00</td>
            <td>16:00</td>
            <td>20:00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
        </table>

    <table class="table table-dark table-striped w-auto text-center m-2">  
        <thead>
            <tr class="bg-primary">
            <th>Przystanek</th>
            <th>(A)</th>     
            <th>(A)</th>   
            <th>(A)</th>   
            <th>(A)</th>   
            </tr>
        </thead>        
        <tbody>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Olsztyn PKP</th>
            <td>09:00</td>
            <td>13:00</td>
            <td>17:00</td>
            <td>21:00</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Dobre Miasto</th>
            <td>09:30</td>
            <td>13:30</td>
            <td>17:30</td>
            <td>21:30</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Kraszewo</th>
            <td>09:50</td>
            <td>13:50</td>
            <td>17:50</td>
            <td>21:50</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <th scope="row">Lidzbark Warmiński</th>
            <td>10:00</td>
            <td>14:00</td>
            <td>18:00</td>
            <td>22:00</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you change your layout a little bit? You can put each table inside a column `col-12` and second table will be positioned below the first one. This is how bootstrap layout works and you don't need extra classes to center tables. Even more - you can adjust table width by changing columns for example to `col-md-8`. You can use offset classes `offset-*` to center them horizontaly.

Here you have Bootstrap DOCS: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/

```css
/*DEMO*/body{padding:3rem}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">


<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 mb-5">
    <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
      <thead><tr class="bg-primary"><th>Przystanek</th><th>(A)</th><th>(A)</th><th>(A)</th><th>(A)</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><th scope="row">Lidzbark Warmiński</th> <td>08:00</td><td>12:00</td><td>15:00</td><td>19:00</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Kraszewo</th><td>08:20</td><td>12:20</td><td>15:20</td><td>19:20</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Dobre Miasto</th><td>08:30</td><td>12:30</td><td>15:30</td><td>19:30</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Olsztyn PKP</th><td>09:00</td><td>13:00</td><td>16:00</td><td>20:00</td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
  <div class="col-8 offset-2">
    <table class="table table-dark table-striped">
      <thead><tr class="bg-primary"><th>Przystanek</th><th>(A)</th><th>(A)</th><th>(A)</th><th>(A)</th></tr></thead><tbody><tr><th scope="row">Olsztyn PKP</th><td>09:00</td><td>13:00</td><td>17:00</td><td>21:00</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Dobre Miasto</th><td>09:30</td><td>13:30</td><td>17:30</td><td>21:30</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Kraszewo</th><td>09:50</td><td>13:50</td><td>17:50</td><td>21:50</td></tr><tr><th scope="row">Lidzbark Warmiński</th><td>10:00</td><td>14:00</td><td>18:00</td><td>22:00</td></tr></tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```